# How to create a boundary vector of objects after using watershed_segmentation python

Tags: python, watershed

I used [watershed segmentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) in opencv-python to separate object. However, after segmentation I don't know how to create boundary polygons of objects (red rounded in the image attached).

[image]